# How to dynamically add pairs of controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel

I'm trying to dynamically add some controls (currently *text boxes* and *labels*) to a form. There isn't a set number of pairs to be drawn`.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve.
[image]

As you can see, the table runs out of space, so it moves over to the right.

Currently, I am using a `TableLayoutPanel` within a `FlowLayoutPanel`.
`Column 0` contains the `label` and `column 1` contains the `textbox`.

How do I, or rather, can I get the `FlowLayoutPanel` to split the table?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FlowLayoutPanel flp = new FlowLayoutPanel()
    {
        Location = new Point(0, 0),
        Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        AutoSize = false,
        FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown,
        AutoScroll = true,
        BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
        WrapContents = true
    };

    Controls.Add(flp);

    TableLayoutPanel tlp = new TableLayoutPanel()
    {
        ColumnCount = 2,
        Height = ClientSize.Height,
        BackColor=Color.AliceBlue
    };

    flp.Controls.Add(tlp);

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        Label _label = new Label()
        {
            Text = i.ToString("00"),
            AutoSize = true
        };

        tlp.Controls.Add(_label, 0, i);

        TextBox _textbox = new TextBox();
        tlp.Controls.Add(_textbox, 1, i);
    }
```

Comment: Use a control designed for dynamically adding fields, like [`DataGridView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview(v=vs.110).aspx), not a `TableLayoutPanel`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `TableLayoutPanel` having 4 columns, and set suitable `ColumnStyles` for the control.

**Example**

Put a button and a panel on the form and set anchors of panel to all edges. Then handle click event of the button and use this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fields = new string[] { "A Field", "Some Field", "Another Field",
        "A Long Field Name", "A Long Long Field Name" };
    var tlp = new TableLayoutPanel() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, ColumnCount = 4 };
    tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
    tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
    tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.AutoSize));
    tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 50));
    panel1.Controls.Add(tlp);
    foreach (var item in fields)
    {
        tlp.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = item, AutoSize = true });
        tlp.Controls.Add(new TextBox() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill });
    }
}
```

[image]